# ActorSystem shutdown in akka stream

Tags: apache-kafka, akka-stream

I have an akka stream which is consuming data from kafka topic continuosly.
I never shutdown the actorsystem ,i do not want my application to shutdown is it the correct way ? What is the correct way to handle actorySystem shutdown?

```
  implicit val actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("mytest")
  implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer =
    ActorMaterializer(ActorMaterializerSettings(actorSystem).withSupervisionStrategy(decider))

  val actorConfig = actorSystem.settings.config.getConfig("akka.kafka.consumer")

  val consumerSettings =
    ConsumerSettings(actorConfig, new StringDeserializer, new StringDeserializer)
      .withBootstrapServers(config.getString("kafka.hosts"))
      .withGroupId("mytestgrp")


  val flow = Consumer
    .atMostOnceSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics(config.getString("kafka.topic")))
    .grouped(500)
    .map(Pipeline.process)
    .withAttributes(supervisionStrategy(decider))

  flow.runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

Answer (score 0):

When the stream completes you can close the actor system

```
flow.runWith(Sink.ignore).onComplete {
    case _ => actorSystem.shutdown
}
```